# Using cURL cookie-jar in PHP

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Suppose I want to make two consecutive curl request. The website needs to send cookies which it stores in first step during second request.

So, I need to close curl connection after first request and then make second curl_int() to make second request as the curl saves cookie-jar file only after closing. right?

Or curl stores and send the cookies automatically until I close curl connection?

IS THERE ANY WAY TO DO IT IN SINGLE CURL_INT()?

Thank You

Comment: why use two curl requests? You can re-use a single curl handle for multiple requests. The cookie files are only to preserve the cookies between different curl handles, or across script invovations. Within a single curl handle, the cookies will be available regardless of the jar/file settings.

Comment: I use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath("cookie.txt")) according to my style. Can you please explain with an example how to pass the cookie during the 2nd request if I use your style(ie, don't save the cookie file in cookie.txt beforehand)?

Comment: `$ch = curl_init($url1); ... do stuff ... ; curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2); ... do other stuff ... `

Comment: Then will it automatically store the cookies of url1 and pass it to url2 when requested?

Comment: yes, as long as you don't close/re-initialize $ch between the two requests.